# Adverb word choice with 遊ぶ

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, spoken-language

I was writing the following message to an exchange friend and I struggled to find adverbs to pair with the verb 遊ぶ, and now I'm wondering a broader question about adverbs in general:

> 兄はカリフォるニアから来ました。私と従兄と＿遊んでいます。

In this case, I wanted to convey the idea of "very", "extremely", "often", or something natural-sounding in Japanese. I thought of adverbs like ずいぶんと and もっと, but neither seemed quite natural or very correct.

More generally, from experience, can you say that there are any adverbs in Japanese that show up very commonly in spoken Japanese (both casual and polite)? In English, we use general adverbs "very", "really" "a lot", "so much", "super" (colloquial), etc that can be used in a wide variety of everyday situations.

**Which Japanese adverbs fill a similar role in (spoken) Japanese?** Also, which adverbs are more polite or academic-sounding, such as the word "quite" in English?

---

Bonus questions:

How would you say the phrase "a game called Risk," or more generally, "a thing called ____", putting emphasis on the fact the speaker probably hasn't heard of the name of the thing? 「ボードゲームのRisk」？

How would you say, "We've been doing things like playing videos games, visiting family, and going out to eat and to watch movies"?　「私たちはビデおゲームをして、家族を訪ねて、食べに出かけて、映画を見に出かけています」？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

兄はカリフォるニアから来ました。私と従兄と＿遊んでいます。
⇒兄がカリフォルニアから来ました、私と従兄と遊んでます。

"very"　とても, "extremely"　すごく, "often"　よく,

quite　まったく、すっかり、完全に

a game called Risk　リスクって言うゲーム、リスクと言うゲーム

「私たちはビデおゲームをして、家族を訪ねて、食べに出かけて、映画を見に出かけています」

⇒　私たちはビデオゲームをしたり、家族を訪ねたり、食べに出かけたり、映画を見に行ったりしました。

Comment: `兄がカリフォルニアから来ました、私と従兄と遊んでます。` --「私と従兄と＿遊んでいます。」の空白部分には、何を入れればよいでしょうか。「とても、すごく、よく、まったく、すっかり、完全に」はすべて使えますか。

Comment: I don't know what you want to say exactly but I would add  毎日(everyday) or よく、たくさん、いっぱい。全部は使えませんね。

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by the first part. I assume that you mean to say that your brother was in California for two weeks, where he played a lot with his cousing.

> 兄は**カリフォニアから**二週間**行っていて**、兄**と**従兄と＿遊**びて**います。

I have made bold your mistakes.

- カリフォニア　ー>　カリフォ**ル**ニア
- から　there does not make sense.
- 行っていて you simply say 行って, otherwise it is as if he is moving continuously
- The first と after 兄 is probably a mistake. The form is: AはBとCと〜する = A does 〜 with B and C, but I suppose that you mean that you have one brother who does something with his cousin. The first と is thus wrong.
- The proper way of conjugating 遊ぶ is 遊んで

The adverb you are looking for is よく, which means "frequently", "excessively", "do something a lot". This is the most neutral way of saying it. It can also mean to do something "well" or "skillfully". What is meant is apparent from the context.

In general, some words for "very", are 非常｛ひじょう｝に(formal) or slangs めっちゃ, バリ etc.

The full sentence is thus:

> 兄は二週間カリフォルニアに行って、いとことよく遊びました。

Note that I changed your sentence to past tense as this makes more sense. If it's about something that is to happen, it would be slightly rewritten at the end.

The other questions ボードゲームのRisk works, otherwise you can be more explicit and say Riskというボードゲーム

The last question, if you use 〜て-form it is as if you do those things sequentially. What you want to use is 〜たり〜する: 私達はテレビゲームをしたり、外食｛がいしょく｝に行ったり、映画を見に行ったりしました

Comment: I see that you have edited your sentence that you want help with and that the meaning is different now. I will leave my answer as it is, as it still answers your main question. In the future, please post what you want to say, in English, as this will help a lot to see what your mistakes are.

Comment: I'd say 「いとこと**たくさん**遊びました」... or more colloquially 「 **いっぱい**遊びました」...  (いとことよく遊びました would sound like 頻繁に/しょっちゅう遊びました, "would often/frequently~~", rather than "really" "a lot" "so much"...)

Comment: I agree, those are better given the complete sentence. He wanted the meaning "often" however...